# Saving listview content to sd-card in android

Tags: android, listview, save, sd-card

I am making an android application that needs to save listview items to the sdcard. I am using a dynamic listview that the users can delete items from and add items to. I want the listview to save the items if the application gets destroyed or if the user hits the back button. Basically when the activity is destroyed. Please help and thanks SO much in advance! I am using this code so far:

```
public class NotesActivity extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
EditText AddItemToListViewEditText;
Button AddItemToListView, AddItemToListViewButton, CancelButton, DeleteButton,CancelButton2, DeleteAllButton;
LinearLayout AddItemToListViewLinearLayout, DeleteItemFromListViewLinearLayout, DeleteAllItemsFromListViewLinearLayout;
public int DeleteIndexNumber;
  static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] {
      "Matte på A1 med Ole", "Engelsk på klasserommet", "Film på A1 etter friminuttet"
      };
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.notes);
    setListAdapter((ListAdapter) new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, COUNTRIES));
    setListAdapter((ListAdapter) new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, myList));

    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
          int position, long id) {
        // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Note: " + ((TextView) view).getText(),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        DeleteIndexNumber = position;
        DeleteItemFromListViewLinearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.DeleteItemFromListViewLinearLayout);
        DeleteItemFromListViewLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  }
    });
  }
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu meny) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.listviewmenubuttons, meny);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.AddItemToListView:
        AddItemToListViewButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.AddItemToListViewButton);
        CancelButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.CancelButton);
        DeleteButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.DeleteButton);
        CancelButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        DeleteButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        AddItemToListViewLinearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.AddItemToListViewLinearLayout);
        AddItemToListViewButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        AddItemToListViewLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        break;
    case R.id.DeleteAllNotes:
        DeleteAllItemsFromListViewLinearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.DeleteAllItemsFromListViewLinearLayout);
        DeleteAllItemsFromListViewLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        CancelButton2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.CancelButton2);
        DeleteAllButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.DeleteAllButton);
        CancelButton2.setOnClickListener(this);
        DeleteAllButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        break;
        }
    return true;
}
public void onClick(View src) {
    switch(src.getId()) {
    case R.id.AddItemToListViewButton:
        AddItemToListViewEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.AddItemToListViewEditText);
        myList.add(AddItemToListViewEditText.getText().toString());
        ((ArrayAdapter)getListView().getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged(); 
        AddItemToListViewEditText.setText("");
        AddItemToListViewEditText.clearFocus();
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.toggleSoftInput (InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.RESULT_HIDDEN);
        imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
        AddItemToListViewLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        break;
    case R.id.CancelButton:
        DeleteItemFromListViewLinearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.DeleteItemFromListViewLinearLayout);
        DeleteItemFromListViewLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        break;
    case R.id.DeleteButton:
        myList.remove(DeleteIndexNumber);
        ((ArrayAdapter)getListView().getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged(); 
        DeleteItemFromListViewLinearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.DeleteItemFromListViewLinearLayout);
        DeleteItemFromListViewLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        break;
    case R.id.DeleteAllButton:
        myList.removeAll(myList);
        ((ArrayAdapter)getListView().getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged(); 
        DeleteAllItemsFromListViewLinearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.DeleteAllItemsFromListViewLinearLayout);
        DeleteAllItemsFromListViewLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        break;
    case R.id.CancelButton2:
        DeleteAllItemsFromListViewLinearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.DeleteAllItemsFromListViewLinearLayout);
        DeleteAllItemsFromListViewLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        break;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: you can either store it in a db or in an xml it's up to you though

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the official guide for data storage. Since your ListView content is large, you can store it into SQLite database. The link for the guide is below:-

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html